# Get width of control with not set width

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview and chart below it.

I want gridview stretch depending on number of columns (not set width) and after that to assign that width to chart.

If I do:

```
chart.Width = gridview.Width.Value;
```

I get 0.0 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work this way, the width you need is the client-side value and you cannot get it from the server-side.
Try moving the resize chart logic to javascript, use the .offsetWidth/.clientWidth properties of the table (gridview). Or you can modify mark-up to make you chart stretch automatically (put the grid and the chart into a common container and stretch the chart to fill the width of the container).

Comment: can you please give sample code how to get clientside width? Thanks.

Comment: you should know the client-side id of your grid view. let's say id = "grid", then your javascript is: var width = document.getElementById('grid').clientWidth;